# Notification every 2 minutes, with QR code, What is it?

Tags: notification, bios

Does anybody knows what is the meaning of [the notification](http://oi61.tinypic.com/110zqzk.jpg), is a QR code and says: KERROPI 20140416-1, BIOS f.0.5 System ID: 21f7?

[image]

This is in Unity, with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I am not signed into any services in this desktop session.